# Как сделать кастомный title bar в UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Я хочу создать подобный title bar в своей приложении как это можно сделать? :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/develop/title-bar

Comment: @EvgeniyZ изучил материал и понял как создавать доп. элементы в title bar ,но вот у меня есть NavigationView и как мне убрать при small  окне кнопку открытия меню и поставить еë в title bar

Comment: Честно, тут я вам не помогу. В WinUI3 это по сути, поведение из коробки, достаточно использовать `NavigationView`, который сам под нужные размеры подстраивается, а чтоб он гармонично смотрелся с заголовком, то достаточно убрать стандартный заголовок при помощи `ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true;`, это освободит всю верхнюю площадь окна (кроме кнопок закрытия). Подробный пример есть в [документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui3#full-customization-example).

Comment: Ну то есть, там идет как, [вот стандартное окно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwNI5.png), у которого есть только `NavigationView`, как видите, сверху заголовок окна присутствует, а `NavigationView` уже сам, в компактном виде перенес "гамбургер" меню к кнопке "назад". Ну а если убрать заголовок, то получим уже [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4imlH.png), как видите, контент просто занял теперь все окно, ибо заголовка попросту нет. Вот имея это, смотрите теперь что конкретно у вас не так, если у вас не переходит "гамбургер" в одну строку, то это уже поведение `NavigationView` не то, что у WinUI3.